# Scapy Variable Length Fields

Tags: python, scapy

I am trying to understand the difference between PacketListField and FieldListField. Can someone let me know how to use them when adding new protocols.

I am also not clear about the StrLenField, FieldLenField and PacketLenField. I am trying to craft a BGP Update message so that I can understand how it works. I see this is how the BGPUpdate message has been defined. When I try to craft the BGP packet I am not sure how to pass the values for Withdrawn Routes field and also nlri field. I am also not sure how to pass values for Path Attributes.

```
>>> pkt=BGPUpdate()
>>> pkt.show()
###[ BGP Update fields ]###
  withdrawn_len= None
  withdrawn= []
  tp_len= None
  \total_path\
  nlri= []
>>>                        

class BGPPathAttribute(Packet):
"the attribute of total path"
    name = "BGP Attribute fields"
    fields_desc = [
    FlagsField("flags", 0x40, 8, ["NA0","NA1","NA2","NA3","Extended-Length","Partial","Transitive","Optional"]), #Extened leght may not work
    ByteEnumField("type", 1, {1:"ORIGIN", 2:"AS_PATH", 3:"NEXT_HOP", 4:"MULTI_EXIT_DISC", 5:"LOCAL_PREF", 6:"ATOMIC_AGGREGATE", 7:"AGGREGATOR"}),
    ByteField("attr_len", None),
    StrLenField("value", "", length_from = lambda p: p.attr_len),
   ]
   def post_build(self, p, pay):
        if self.attr_len is None:
            l = len(p) - 3 # 3 is regular length with no additional options
            p = p[:2] + struct.pack("!B",l)  +p[3:]
        return p+pay
    def extract_padding(self, p):
        """any thing after this packet is extracted is padding"""
        return "",p

class BGPUpdate(Packet):
    """Update the routes WithdrawnRoutes = UnfeasiableRoutes"""
    name = "BGP Update fields"
    fields_desc = [
        ShortField("withdrawn_len", None),
        FieldListField("withdrawn",[], BGPIPField("","0.0.0.0/0"), length_from=lambda p:p.withdrawn_len),
        ShortField("tp_len", None),
        PacketListField("total_path", [], BGPPathAttribute, length_from = lambda p: p.tp_len),
        FieldListField("nlri",[], BGPIPField("","0.0.0.0/0"), length_from=lambda p:p.underlayer.len - 23 - p.tp_len - p.withdrawn_len), # len should be BGPHeader.len
        ]
    def post_build(self,p,pay):
        wl = self.withdrawn_len
        subpacklen = lambda p: len ( str( p ))
        subfieldlen = lambda p: BGPIPField("", "0.0.0.0/0").i2len(self,  p )
        if wl is None:
            wl = sum ( map ( subfieldlen , self.withdrawn))
            p = p[:0]+struct.pack("!H", wl)+p[2:]
        if self.tp_len is None:
            l = sum ( map ( subpacklen , self.total_path))
            p = p[:2+wl]+struct.pack("!H", l)+p[4+wl:]
        return p+pay
```

Answer (score 6):

They just operate on different kinds of objects. see [scapy build dissect](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/build_dissect.html)

**PacketListField**

describes a list of *PacketFields* of the same type whereas one *PacketField* represents a *Packet* type object put into another packets field. It takes a Packet prototype as the third parameter *cls* `__init__(self, name, default, cls, count_from=None, length_from=None)`. The constructor of the PacketListField either requires the count_from (number of objects) or lengt_from (bytes) arguments being set in order to know how many bytes to pass to the packetlist or how many object to dissect.(e.g. you can have `BGPUpdate` as the prototype of a PacketField or PacketListField).

For example:

```
PacketListField("total_path", [], BGPPathAttribute, length_from = lambda p: p.tp_len),
```

creats a Field called "total_path", with a default value of an empty list [], and tries to dissect up to length_from bytes of the raw_bytestream as BGPPathAttribute(Packet).

**FieldListField**

In contrast the *FieldListField* takes a Field as the prototype and tries to dissect the raw_bytestream as a list of prototype fields `__init__(self, name, default, field, length_from=None, count_from=None):`

```
FieldListField("withdrawn",[], BGPIPField("","0.0.0.0/0"), length_from=lambda p:p.withdrawn_len),
```

**StrLenField**

DataField that typically holds up to length_from bytes `__init__(self, name, default, fld=None, length_from=None):`.

**FieldLenField**

Numeric field that holds the length of another field in the same packet `__init__(self, name, default,  length_of=None, fmt = "H", count_of=None, adjust=lambda pkt,x:x, fld=None):`

```
class SomePacket(Packet):
    name = "SomePacket"
    fields_desc = [ByteEnumField("type", 0x00, {0x00:"SomeType"}),  
                  FieldLenField("length", None, length_of="data"),          # hold length of data
                  StrLenField("data", "", length_from=lambda x:x.length),   # holds data
                  ]
```

*On dissect*, scapy will put the first byte into 'type', the next 2 bytes (default fmt="H" for short into the short integer "length", and up to 'length' bytes into 'data'

*On build*, scapy will automatically fill 'length' with len(data).

**PacketLenField**

Is a field that dissects length_from bytes as one prototype Packet `__init__(self, name, default, cls, length_from=None):`

```
class AnotherPacket(Packet):
    name = "AnotherPacket"
    fields_desc = [
                  BLenField("length", None, length_of="data"),
                  PacketLenField("data", None, SomePacket, length_from=lambda x:x.length),]
                  ]
```

*On dissect*, scapy will put the first Byte into the ByteLengthField 'length' and up to 'length' bytes dissected as 'SomePacket' into 'data'

*On build*, scapy will automatically fill 'length' with the size of the serialized SomePacket.