# scapy - add a new protocol - length variable

Tags: scapy

Im trying to add a new protocol and I have difficulties with the following members:

1. 2-bytes member which suppose to be the length of the string A
2. A - a unicode string which is not terminated with null.

I need to read the length X and according to it take X bytes of the string A.

Can someone help me to.understand how to implement the length variable and the unicode string?

Thanks

Comment: in php it'd be `$binary=pack ( 'v', strlen($str) ).$str;` (note that php's strlen() counts bytes, not unicode characters, and php's strings are binary strings, not adhering to any character encoding scheme/charset.) idk how to handle binary data in python tho.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scapy Variable Length Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27163340/scapy-variable-length-fields)